# A unbounded exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

Could you tell me how to show that the function $f(y)=xy-e^x$ is unbounded if $y <0$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be a fixed parameter?  As a function of $y$ with fixed $x$, it's a polynomial of degree $1$ and slope $x$.  It's unbounded below on $(-\infty, 0)$ if $x > 0$, unbounded above there if $x < 0$, but constant (and thus bounded) if $x=0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yeah. $x$ is a fixed value. It is a good idea to see $f(y)$ is a linear function. However, I wonder the case $y>0$, why is the function bounded with $y >0$?

Comment: It isn't bounded on $(0,\infty)$, unless $x=0$.